# customize sidebar.php woocommerce bootstrap

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to customize the woocommerce sidebar. I was able to find the template named `sidebar.php` but it only contain the `get_sidebar('shop')` function, but there is no `sidebar-shop.php` file inside the woocommerce templates folder. I'm not able to customize it to place it on the right side of the screen. I've setted up bootstrap rows and classes for almost all of the main templates files, but also if I set three products per row and `col-3`, the sidebar will stay to the bottom of the page. I'm using hooks as suggested from docs. Can anyone guide me please?